# Glass SitecoreContentContext has Database property null

Tags: glass-mapper

I'm trying to get the Sitecore context using:

```csharp
var context = new SitecoreContentContext();
var item = context.GetItem<Sitecore.Data.Items.Item>("/sitecore/content/home");
```

But the item assignment throws a Null Exception Error. When I debug the context variable, the property `Database` is null. If I set that property to "master" on debug mode, it works. But I don't know why that property null.

[image]

Does any one have any advice?

Thanks

Comment: What is the execution context of your code? Are you inside of a controller?  Do you have `Sitecore.Context.ContentDatabase` available at that time?

Comment: As @DmytroShevchenko asked, the execution context of your code is very important. Exactly where is this being run? You may want to consider using the following switcher if it's being run in an abnormal way (through a job or even a SPEAK application): `Sitecore.Data.DatabaseSwitcher`

Comment: @gunarb Please consider marking the answer that helped you the most as accepted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is you want to use the database represented by `Sitecore.Context.Database` then you should use `SitecoreContext`.

The service SitecoreContentContext is a wrapper for the database `Sitecore.Context.ContentDatabase`.

If the internal database used by the Glass service is null, you should check the appropriate static property.

If you want to wrap a specific  database you should use `SitecoreService` e.g: `new SitecoreService("master")`.

If you want to just grab a Sitecore Item, as in this code:

`var item = context.GetItem<Sitecore.Data.Items.Item>("/sitecore/content/home");`

Then you are probably better just using the Sitecore Database itself. Use Glass when you are working with models and not raw Sitecore items.

Answer (score 3):

This error happens when your code is in an environment that doesn't have a Sitecore context or doesn't have a content database assigned.

To solve this,

- Either move your code to a Sitecore-powered environment (such an MVC controller);
- Or register the way your code executes in Sitecore (e.g. if it's an .svc service, add `svc` to the list of allowed extensions);
- Or pass in the content database directly:

```cs
var context = new SitecoreContentContext(
    Factory.GetDatabase("master"),
    AbstractSitecoreContext.GetContextFromSite())
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your item to make sure a version exists in the language you are opening the site in.

Also make sure the item is published and is in the web database. The fact that you see it in the debug mode shows that its in master but might not be in web.

Answer (score 1):

You can fill up your database variable using the following statement:

```cs
Sitecore.Data.DatabasemasterDB = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
```

But i would recommend trying to sort it out like this:

```cs
Item item1 = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("/sitecore/content/home");
```

It will then retrieve the designated database out of its context instead of "forcing" to use a specific database. Let e know if this worked out for you.